# Best way to include stdafx.h, when it is 1 directory up?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stdafx.h

Imagine the following source files:

```
src/StdAfx.h
src/moresrc/MyFile.cpp
```

In `MyFile.cpp`, I need to include the precompiled header file StdAfx.h.

If I do this:

```
#include "../StdAfx.h"
```

then I will get the compiler error:

```
warning C4627: '#include "../stdafx.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?
```

So that doesn't work. If I do just

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
```

then that compiles correctly, but I get the annoying error highlighting in Visual Studio 2013 that looks like this:

[image: error highlighting]

So, like I said, this compiles, but it is annoying.

How can I include "StdAfx.h" without the underlining, but so that it will compile?

Comment: File a bug report to Microsoft? ;)

Comment: I suggest you not use precompile headers and remove stdafx.h from your project.  Unless you have a huge project, the savings in time of the precompiled headers does not outweigh the hassle it causes, like the issue you are facing.

Comment: The precompiled headers are supposed to save time, but if one of the headers changes, the precompilation process needs to be performed.  The idea would be to place the stable headers into "precompiled" section and the volatile ones outside.

Comment: The red squiggly underline is under the `#include`, not under the header name. If I recall correctly, you can right-click or hover on the underline to see what it's complaining about. Does giving the header name in lower case make a difference?

Comment: @keith-thompson : the tooltip for the squiggly line complains: "Error: cannot open source file 'stdafx.h'". And changing the case to StdAfx.h or anything else does nothing.

Comment: @dan-O: That's important information; please include it in the question. If the code compiles but the tooltip complains that it can't open the source file, that sounds like a bug in whatever produces the tooltip (or maybe there's some configuration you need to tweak). Using precompiled headers may or may not be a good idea, but I wouldn't think the red squiggly line is a good reason to avoid them.

Comment: The same question seems to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434123/how-to-include-the-stdafx-h-from-the-root-directory

Answer (score 5):

You can add `$(ProjectDir)` (project root directory) to directories list in project options (C++ -> General -> Additional Include directories). Then you'll be able to specify paths relative to project root in includes. For instance if you have `utils/a.h` and want to use it from `foo/bar/b.h` you can write `#include "utils/a.h"` instead of `#include "../../utils/a.h"`. And if you have `stdafx.h` in project root you can include it with just `#include "stdafx.h"`.