# Visual Studio 2017 - including stdafx.h doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have add a new filter "External" at the same level as "Header Files" and "Source Files". External filter also contains filters: include and lib. There is also the same directory structure in the windows explorer view. Next I have added exisiting items to the include and lib filters (x.h and x.cpp respectively). x.cpp in lib filter has the following include:

```
#include "../../StdAfx.h"
```

StdAfx.h file is placed in "Headers Files". Visual Studio sees that include but when I compile program I get the following info for x.cpp:

```
unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?
```

What's going on ? It's weird that visual studio see that include and later the file is not included. How to fix that ?

**Edit:**

x.cpp

```
#include "../../StdAfx.h"
#include "../include/myHeader.h"

void fun()
{}
```

Comment: You need to tell the compiler about the file in the project settings too.

Comment: The inclusion of the precompiled header file must be the *first* non-comment, non-space "statement" in the source files.

Comment: It is, please see Edit. For cpp files which are placed in the "Source Files" including "StdAfx.h" from the "Header Files" works fine.

Comment: Ahh, another victim of precompiled headers. Just disable them.

Comment: Depends on the VS2017 version, somewhere half-way they changed the default name from stdafx.h to pch.h.  Project > Properties > C/C++ > Precompiled Headers > "Precompiled header file" setting.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434123/how-to-include-the-stdafx-h-from-the-root-directory/37709456#37709456